# Scrap google folder of files and update master with updated information (appscript)

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a master google sheet that I would like to pull all data in a folder of roughly 200 files (will continue to have new files added). They have the same format. The headers are A2:F2 and I would call all rows until the F Column is empty.

Next step would be to be able to run the script as needed to run through the files and update/add any new information. I created a scrape that takes and finds the Ids of each sheet.

I've tried finding ways to utilize the scrape of file IDs and expand it out. I started creating a loop, but can't find the solution of how to build it out.

Answer (score 0):

Move Data to Master Sheet

```
function moveDataToMasterSheet(folderid="folderid") {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
  fnf(folder);
}

function fnf(folder) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const msh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    let tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
    tss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
      try {
      let vs = sh.getRange("A2:F" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
      vs.unshift([`FILE: ${file.getName()}`, `CREATIONDDATE: ${file.getDateCreated()}`, `SHEET:${sh.getName()}`, '', '',''])
      msh.getRange(msh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
      } 
      catch(e) {
        Logger.log([`FILE: ${file.getName()}`, `CREATIONDDATE: ${file.getDateCreated()}`, `SHEET:${sh.getName()}`, '', '',''])
        Logger.log(e);
      }
    })
  }
  let subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder = subfolders.next();
    fnf(subfolder);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested it this before I posted it

Comment: What are the exact error messages